# Xamarin - how to make a CollectionView with grid responsive

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, responsive, collectionview

I was wondering how it could be possible to create a xamarin application using collectionview and make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution that you can find here:
[Xamarin-ResponsiveApp](https://github.com/flaubertlekhem/Xamarin-ResponsiveApp)

Here is the result:

[image: Image result]

Comment: Yes but i cannot mark my how response has an answer. Even if it is.